# Iterating through a text file and assigning variables for each line

Tags: c++, object, c++11, vector, ifstream

having a difficult time finding a way to assign each line of the text file being read to a different variable, i commented above the variables displaying how a line from the text file displaying that variable would look. I want to know what way i can use a forloop to be able to iterate through the entire text file and store data to each of the variables I commented above based on the type of data it needs to store. The three sets of variables all have to be stored by species and in a way they can be manipulated. How can i split up a vector into a set of three variables?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string getInputFileName()
//retrieves the inputfile
{
    string fileName;
    ifstream inputfile;

    //prompting user for filename to be opened
    cout << "Enter the file name to be opened: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    //opening the file for input
    inputfile.open(fileName, ios::in);

    //checks to see if writing the input file failed
    if (inputfile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Opening file..." << fileName;
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "The " << fileName << "could not be opened! \n";
        cout << "1. Check if file exists. \n";
        cout << "2. Check file path. \n;";

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File: " << fileName << " was successfully opened!" << endl;
        return fileName;
    }

}
string getOutputFileName()
//retrieves the inputfile
{
    string fileName;
    ofstream outputfile;

    //prompting user for filename to be opened
    cout << "Enter the file name to be opened: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    //opening the file for input
    outputfile.open(fileName, ios::in);

    //checks to see if writing the input file failed
    if (outputfile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Opening file..." << fileName;
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "The " << fileName << "could not be opened! \n";
        cout << "1. Check if file exists. \n";
        cout << "2. Check file path. \n;";

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File: " << fileName << " was successfully opened!" << endl;
        return fileName;
    }

}


int main()
{
    //opens clasfication file
    ifstream inputFile(getInputFileName());

    //declaring year and numberOfSpecies
    int year, numberOfSpecies;
    string line;

    if (inputFile.is_open())
    {
        //year of file
        inputFile >> year;
        //echo for year
        cout << year << endl;

        //number of species of file
        inputFile >> numberOfSpecies;
        //echo for number of species
        cout << numberOfSpecies << endl;

        string line;

        //variables i need to assign line by line and be able to manipulate
        //region of species would look like this in text file: 84
        //nameOfspecies would like like this in the text file: Spotted Gecko
        //regionSightings would look like this in the text file: 84 95 30 25



        vector<string> linesOfData;

    for (int i = 0; (!inputFile.eof()) || (i <= numberOfSpecies) ; i++)
    {

        getline(inputFile, line, '\n');
        linesOfData.push_back(line);

        //echo vector!
        cout << linesOfData[i] << "\n";

        }
        ofstream outputFile(getOutputFileName());

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to solve several problems at once. Break it down, solve a simpler problem first. And develop new functionality *in isolation*, not embedded in a large body of other code.

Comment: What simpler problem would be the first thing i solve for?

Comment: I'd use a `std::vector<string>` to hold each line of the text file. I'd first read the file line-by-line into successive elements of this vector and close the file. I'd then go through and break up the read lines into each instance of a species you've recorded. Each group of three lines would populate each of th 3 attributes that a species has. You'd just need special handling for the first 2 lines as you have already.

Comment: thanks, Im working on using vectors right now, i'll update code as soon as I am done.

Comment: How would i go about setting up a vector that would take in information for groups of tree? I cant seem to find any resources where i can pull the information.

Comment: Rather than just commenting on the different kinds of values that are in each line, why not comment on what each line **actually looks like**, and then explain how it needs to be broken up. For instance, based on your comments, I am assuming that each line might look like this: `84 Spotted Gecko 84 95 30 25`, am I right?

Comment: each variable is on a different line, so 84 '\n', Spotted Gecko '\n', 84 95 30 25 '\n'

Comment: You can't open an `ofstream` for input.

Comment: It's opening an ofstream for output to output different averages based on the information i take in from the ifstream.

Comment: @user3236101: Then you are not dealing with 1 line per species, you are dealing with 3 lines per species. That should have been explained up front, as that affects how you read the data.

Comment: Well since we figured out that I cant explain things very well, how in the world would i go about manipulating the vector to store the 3 lines per species? Would i have to use another vector?

Comment: @user3236101: I would not use a `vector` of `string` values. I would use a `vector` of `struct` values instead, where each `struct` holds the data for a species. While looping through the input file, read 3 lines at a time, parse them into a `struct`, and then push it into the `vector`.  See my answer for an example.

Comment: `outputfile.open(fileName, ios::in);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code for your requirements. You will have to fill in the code and do the required testing. 
I have used similar logic many times for my requirements. I see this to be more maintainable and scalable.

```
class spotted_species{
    private:
        int first_val[];
        string species_name;
        int locations[];

    // Private methods
    private:
        void assign_species_firstVal (String first_line){
            Assign the first line after performing required transformations;
        }

        int  assign_species_name (String Second_Line){
            if (the species name exists in predefined array or file) {
                assign the name;
            }
            else {
                return -1; // to ignore all 3 lines. 
            }
        }

        void assign_species_locations (String third_line){
            tokenize by space
            convert each token to int and assign. hardly 2 lines code.
        }

    // Public methods
    public:
        void show_species(){
            std::cout<< "First val";
            std::cout<< "Species name";
            std::cout<< "Spotted locations";
        }

        int init(String firstline, String secondline, String ThirdLine){
            assign_species_firstVal(firstline);

            int status = assign_species_name (secondline);
            if (status) {
                assign_species_locations (ThirdLine);
            }

            return status_accordingly;
        }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Create an array of spotted_species to ensure you can hold the required number of 
    // species from the file. 
    run a OS command "WC -l" which gives the total number of line in your file. 
    All file handling could be done here based on the output of the above command. 

    // Calculate the number of objects you would need based on the number of lines. 
    // Rough estimate would be fine for these requirements.   
    int num_species = lines_in_file/3 + 10; // +10 is used to be on safer side. 

    // Create the objects
    spotted_species species_spotted_in_africa[num_species];

    int ctr;
    while (read file until the last line)
        // Read 3 lines at a go, 
        // store them in 3 variables. 
        // call init with all 3 arguments. 
    }

    // Now you have all the species information in seperate objects. 
    // you can access them in a loop or by any other means.

    // If you need to perform any additional processing on these objects, 
    //     you always can extend this class or 
    //     you could write another class which can process this class data. 

    // Flexible, simple, Maintainable and scalable. 
    return 0;
}
```

You will have to make some changes as per your exact requirements. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you have 3 lines of data per species, eg:

```
84
Spotted Gecko
84 95 30 25
```

I would suggest using a `vector` of `struct` values instead of `string` values, where each `struct` holds the data for a single species.  While looping through the input file, read 3 lines at a time, parse them into an instance of the `struct`, and then push it into* the `vector`.

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct species
{
    int region;
    string name;
    std::vector<int> regionSightings;
};

bool openInputFile(ifstream &inputfile)
{
    string fileName;

    //prompting user for filename to be opened
    cout << "Enter the input file to be opened: ";
    getline(cin, filename);

    //opening the file for input
    cout << "Opening file: " << filename << endl;
    inputfile.open(fileName);

    //checks to see if opening the input file failed
    if (!inputfile)
    {
        cout << "File: " << fileName << " could not be opened!" << endl;
        cout << "1. Check if file exists." << endl;
        cout << "2. Check file path." << endl;

        return false;
    }

    cout << "File: " << fileName << " was successfully opened!" << endl;
    return true;
}

bool openOutputFile(ofstream &outputfile)
{
    string fileName;

    //prompting user for filename to be opened
    cout << "Enter the output file to be opened: ";
    getline(cin, filename);

    //opening the file for input
    cout << "Opening file: " << fileName << endl;
    outputfile.open(fileName);

    //checks to see if opening the output file failed
    if (!outputfile)
    {
        cout << "File: " << fileName << " could not be opened!" << endl;
        cout << "1. Check if file exists." << endl;
        cout << "2. Check file path." << endl;

        return false;
    }

    cout << "File: " << fileName << " was successfully opened!" << endl;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    //opens clasfication file
    ifstream inputFile;
    if (openInputFile(inputFile))
    {
        //declaring year and numberOfSpecies
        int year, numberOfSpecies;
        string line;

        //year of file
        inputFile >> year;
        //echo for year
        cout << "Year: " << year << endl;

        //number of species in file
        inputFile >> numberOfSpecies;
        //echo for number of species
        cout << "# species: " << numberOfSpecies << endl;

        //there are three lines per species
        //region of species, eg: 84
        //nameOfspecies, eg: Spotted Gecko
        //regionSightings, eg: 84 95 30 25

        vector<species> speciesData;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSpecies; ++i)
        {
            species s;

            if (!getline(inputFile, line))
            {
                cout << "File: " << fileName << " could not read a species region!" << endl;
                break;
            }

            if (!(istringstream(line) >> s.region))
            {
                cout << "File: " << fileName << " could not parse a species region!" << endl;
                break;
            }

            if (!getline(inputFile, s.name))
            {
                cout << "File: " << fileName << " could not read a species name!" << endl;
                break;
            }

            if (!getline(inputFile, line))
            {
                cout << "File: " << fileName << " could not read a species sightings!" << endl;
                break;
            }

            istringstream iss(line);
            int num;

            while (iss >> num)
                s.regionSightings.push_back(num);

            if (!iss.eof())
            {
                cout << "File: " << fileName << " could not parse a species sightings!" << endl;
                break;
            }

            speciesData.push_back(s);

            //echo vector!
            cout << s.region << " " << s.name << " " << line << endl;
        }

        cout << "Closing input file" << endl;
        inputFile.close();

        ofstream outputFile;
        if (openOutputFile(outputFile))
        {
            for (std::vector<species>::iterator iter = speciesData.begin();
                iter != speciesData.end();
                ++iter)
            {
                species &s = *iter;

                // write species data to outputFile as needed...
            }

            cout << "Closing output file" << endl;
        }

        cout << "Finished" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this code is not echoing back the vector for some reason or another?

Comment: It only echoes out each species that is successfully read. If it does not echo, then it is not reading the species. Did you try running it in a debugger to see what is actually happening?

Comment: I changed the echo line to use `endl` instead out `\n`. Remember that `cout` is buffered, `endl` flushes the buffer, `\n` does not.  Though the next `endl` inside of `openOutputFile()` would have done a flush.

Comment: Even with the echo line changed, there is still no change on my end, the debugging is still saying everything is fine. There isn't any data being echo'ed, from running it i can tell the issue is with how the region information is being parsed.

Comment: So now i got it to run now, but it is still failing to store the region sighted information, its returning a bad value. -858993460

Comment: This is getting ridiculous. You are not providing useful info, there is a lot of guesswork in this discussion.  Please edit your question to show the latest code you are actually using, and please show a sample of data from the actual file, say the first 11 lines, or upload the actual file online somewhere it can be downloaded from.